# Changing size of modal dialog ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog

How to I change the size of modal dialog? Why is this not working?

```
SlingDialogViewController *slingDialog = [[SlingDialogViewController alloc] init];

    slingDialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    slingDialog.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    slingDialog.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 700);
    [self presentModalViewController:slingDialog animated:YES];
```

Comment: I suggest you reading `View Programming Guide for iOS`. You definitely on a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
SlingDialogViewController *slingDialog = [[SlingDialogViewController alloc] init];

slingDialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
slingDialog.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

slingDialog.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 700);
slingDialog.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

It's important to call `presentViewController:animated:completion` first, from my experience at least.

Comment: The dialog is slightly to the left and to far down. Is there anyway to lift it up a bit. I tried changing the CGRect and also commented out the view.superview.center = self.view.center and that didn't worked.

Comment: Sounds like you're running in landscape more and the controller thinks it's in portrait. How does it look when the device is in portrait? Do your controllers allow multiple orientations?

Comment: Sorry for late reply but I was running in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

The modal controllers in iOS have fixed sizes. I don't recommend trying to change them, it never works reliably.

A workaround is to implement it by yourself. A modal (presented) controller is a very simple functionality:

1. A view overlapping your presenting controller, so that it can't be clicked (and it is dimming the contents to make them look backgroundish)
2. A child view controller (and its view) added to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Based on mprivat's answer in a controller being presented:

```
override func viewIsAppearing(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewIsAppearing(animated)

    guard let superview = view.superview else {
        return
    }
    let intrinsicHeight = self.view.bounds.height
    let adjusted = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: intrinsicHeight)
    let height = superview.bounds.size.height
    superview.frame = adjusted
    if var center = presentingViewController?.view.center {
        center.y = superview.bounds.size.height + intrinsicHeight / 2
        superview.center = center
    }
}
```

This works on iOS 16.7.1 on 3rd gen SE.
Original solution did not work for me.

UPD: but it killed the blur/darker background above the modal.